# 1099-int concern, tax filing

Tags: united-states, income-tax, bonds, interest, form-1099-int

My credit union issued me a 1099-int for savings bonds that were cashed in 2023.  Is it correct to say that box 3 of the 1099-int be the total of the interest earned plus half the face value of the bond?  This is the explanation the credit union gave to me, when I questioned why the had such a high interest amount on the 1099-int.

Comment: How long was the bond for, and/or at what prices did you purchase and sell it? If it doubled in value since you bought it then yes, half the sale price would be taxable income, though I'm not sure whether that gets reported as interest or capital gain.

Comment: EE bonds that matured in 2023 were issued in 1993, and EE bonds issued before mid-1995 were sold (arbitrarily) at half their nominal value, which was effectively ignored. The actual gain from interest compounded over 30 years is significantly more than the face value. (Even 4% _simple_ interest x 30 would be more.)

Answer (score 2):

No, box 3 is interest only. However, if you've held these bonds for many years, then it would be the *total* interest accumulated. If you've reported interest as it accrued, you'll need to do some math to adjust (see [Publication 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2023_publink100010051)).